# Input html file type + post form + button type="button" + jquery + MVC 2.0 + Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having one requirement in MVC 2.0 and asp.net.

i am using one partial user control view and using that i want to upload multiple files.
but how to post the form without using input button type='submit'.

i have to use only button type=button and have to post the form so that i can get uploaded files in the controller using Request.Files.

Any help is appreciate. this has to be done using jquery + MVC 2.0 + asp.net.

is there any way to do this ?? i have tried ajax.. the form is post but not able to get the files.

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with the uploadify plugin for jquery. It can auto upload multiple files as soon as they are selected without needing to submit a form.

http://www.uploadify.com/